# Preciso listar a quantidade de um produto 'X' que cada cliente comprou

Tags: mysql, sql-select

Abaixo segue a estrutura e relacionamentos do meu banco de dados.
[image: estrutura e relacionamentos do banco de dados Nota.]

tentei usar o código :

```
`SELECT `cliente`.`Nome`, `produto`.`Descricao`, 
 `contem`.`QuantItem`
 FROM `cliente`, `produto`, `contem`
 INNER JOIN `pedido`
 ON `cliente`.`Codigo` = `pedido`.`Codigo`
 INNER JOIN `contem`
 ON `contem`.`numero` = `pedido`.`Numero`
 WHERE `contem`.`Codigo` = 1;`
```

porem apresenta o seguinte erro na hora de executar: #1066 - Tabela/alias 'contem' não única.

Gostaria de saber como posso corrigir e/ou o que devo fazer para que possa mostrar o resultado desejado.

Agradeço desde já a colaboração de todos.

Comment: @CaiqueRomero mas se ele quer pegar conteúdo das outras duas tabelas (produto.Descricao, contem.QuantItem) como irá olhar apenas para uma tabela?

Comment: @R.Santos infelizmente corrigindo isso, ainda continua o mesmo erro.

Comment: @CaiqueRomero, cara tentei isso que sugeriu, porém apresentou o seguinte erro: #1054 - Coluna 'produto.Descricao' desconhecida em 'field list', creio que deve ser necessário que permaneça eles na declaração.

Comment: Escrevi errado tire somente o contem que está no FROM, me avise se funcionar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você deseja pode ser conseguido somando o agrupamento de acordo com o cliente:

```
SELECT cli.Nome AS cliente,
       prod.Descricao AS produto,
       SUM(co.QuantItem) AS quantidade
  FROM cliente cli
       INNER JOIN pedido p ON p.Codigo = cli.Codigo
       INNER JOIN contem co ON co.Numero = p.Numero
       INNER JOIN produto prod ON prod.Codigo = co.Codigo
 WHERE co.Codigo = 1
 GROUP BY cli.Nome,
          prod.Descricao
```

Comment: perfeito. Esse código apresentou o resultado esperado. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

A tabela contem aparece duas vezes em sua query, remova ela do from

```
SELECT cliente.Nome
  , produto.Descricao 
  , contem.QuantItem
FROM cliente
INNER JOIN pedido
   ON cliente.Codigo = pedido.Codigo
INNER JOIN contem
   ON contem.Numero = pedido.Numero
INNER JOIN produto
   ON produto.Codigo = contem.Codigo
WHERE contem.Codigo = 1;
```

Comment: da essa menssagem de erro.
#1054 - Coluna 'cliente.Codigo' desconhecida em 'on clause'